# How to save the contents obtained by request in a variable

Tags: node.js, node-request

I want to assign the content of the site acquired by specifying by URL to a variable.

### Source

request-sample.js

```
var request = require('request');

var html = '';

request('https://www.google.com', function(error, response, body) {
  html = body;
});

// Below, proceed with processing using saved contents
console.log(html);
```

### Result

```
$ node request-sample.js
$
(Nothing is output...)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: do `console.log(html)` inside the callback  `request('https://www.google.com', function(error, response, body) {
  html = body;
  console.log(html);
});`

Comment: @p0k8_ Thank you for your quick answer! I would like to use saved content outside of request. Can not you do that?

Comment: have a look at promises and async.js

Comment: @p0k8_ Thank you for information! After examining, I found a [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise). This seems to be solved.

Comment: @ponury-kostek Thank you for information! I will refer to the linked article.

Comment: @ina6ra yes using request-promise, you can perform your stuffs, after the successful `.then` handler

Comment: @p0k8_ It solved it by using [sync-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request). It seems to be deprecated, but I just want to use it for testing, so it is good.